# Python: How to traverse a List[Dict{List[Dict{}]}]

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, traversal

I was just wondering if there is a simple way to do this.  I have a particular structure that is parsed from a file and the output is a list of a dict of a list of a dict.  Currently, I just have a bit of code that looks something like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(data)):
    for j, k in data[i].iteritems():
        for l in xrange(len(data[i]['data'])):
            for m, n in data[i]['data'][l].iteritems():
                dostuff()
```

I just wanted to know if there was a function that would traverse a structure and internally figure out whether each entry was a list or a dict and if it is a dict, traverse into that dict and so on.  I've only been using Python for about a month or so, so I am by no means an expert or even an intermediate user of the language.  Thanks in advance for the answers.

EDIT: Even if it's possible to simplify my code at all, it would help.

Comment: No, there isn't such a function built in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *never* need to iterate through `xrange(len(data))`. You iterate either through `data` (for a list) or `data.items()` (or `values()`) (for a dict).

Your code should look like this:

```
for elem in data:
    for val in elem.itervalues():
        for item in val['data']:
```

which is quite a bit shorter.

Comment: To add to this: If you want the index of a value as well as the value, you do `for (i,elem) in enumerate(data):`

Comment: Thank you, I knew there had to be a simpler way, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: Ok, now I have another question.  In my example code, say I wanted to access: if data[i][more_data] == 'a_dict'.  When I try doing data[elem][more_data], I of course get the error: list index must be int not dict.  I think that's why I did it the way I did because I couldn't figure out how to access each individual element and check it.

Comment: `for elem in data` deals with element-access for you, behind the scenes. It's basically like doing `for i in xrange(len(data)): elem = data[i]`. So the line of code you're having trouble with should be something like `elem[more_data]` instead of `data[i][more_data]`.

Comment: Wow, I'm a bum. I just now realized I could have been doing something like i['more_data'] the entire time. Thanks @poorsod

Answer (score 5):

Will, if you're looking to decend an arbitrary structure of array/hash thingies then you can create a function to do that based on the `type()` function.

```
def traverse_it(it):
    if (isinstance(it, list)):
        for item in it:
            traverse_it(item)
    elif (isinstance(it, dict)):
        for key in it.keys():
            traverse_it(it[key])
    else:
        do_something_with_real_value(it)
```

Note that the average object oriented guru will tell you not to do this, and instead create a class tree where one is based on an array, another on a dict and then have a single function to process each with the same function name (ie, a virtual function) and to call that within each class function.  IE, if/else trees based on types are "bad".  Functions that can be called on an object to deal with its contents in its own way "good".

Comment: `isinstance(it, list)` and `isinstance(it, dict)` is better than `type(it) == type([])`. It's more readable, and it'll work on subclasses of list and dict. Of course, if "duck typing" is necessary this approach won't work at all and would have to be replaced with a `try...except`-centric style.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do.  There is no need to use `xrange()` to pull out the index from the list since `for` iterates over each *value* of the list.  In my example below `d1` is therefore a reference to the current `data[i]`.

```
for d1 in data: # iterate over outer list, d1 is a dictionary
    for x in d1: # iterate over keys in d1 (the x var is unused)
        for d2 in d1['data']: # iterate over the list

            # iterate over (key,value) pairs in inner most dict
            for k,v in d2.iteritems():
                dostuff()
```

You're also using the name `l` twice (intentionally or not), but beware of how the scoping works.

Comment: Yea, it was supposed to be m and n.

Answer (score 0):

well, question is quite old. however, out of my curiosity, I would like to respond to your question for much better answer which I just tried.
Suppose, dictionary looks like: `dict1 = { 'a':5,'b': [1,2,{'a':100,'b':100}], 'dict 2' : {'a':3,'b':5}}`

Solution:

`dict1 = { 'a':5,'b': [1,2,{'a':100,'b':100}], 'dict 2' : {'a':3,'b':5}}
def recurse(dict):
     if type(dict) == type({}):
        for key in dict:
            recurse(dict[key])
    elif type(dict) == type([]):
        for element in dict:
            if type(element) == type({}):
               recurse(element)
            else:
                print element
    else:
        print dict
recurse(dict1)`

Comment: I suggest not using dict and list as names.

Comment: dict and list are not used like names, these collections are used as objects here.

Comment: You're using `dict` as a variable name. It might be valid but can be confusing for others reading your code.